# Dynamic property keys and values on Typescript Interface dependent on other fields

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript and I'm wondering if there's a way to accomplish the following:

I want to type a few properties that I'm sending to Hubspot through two different endpoints of theirs, each of those APIs take in data using a key named `property` and the other called `name`. 
Which means that they can look like this:

```
{
  property: 'email',
  value: 'test@email.com'
}
```

Or:

```
{
  name: 'email',
  value: 'test@email.com'
}
```

Then, I want to validate that I'm only sending some specific fields. Say this:

```
export interface HubspotFields {
  newsletter: boolean;
  name: string;
  email: string;
}
```

So, is there a way to do something like this?:

```
export interface Test {
  [either "property" or "name"]: [keyof HubspotFields (value can only be one of the keys from HubspotFields)];
  value: [the type of the corresponding dynamic keyof HubspotFields (string 
 boolean)];
}
```

In other words:

```
//This fails
{
  something: 'email',
  value: 'test@email.com'
}
//This fails
{
  property: 'something',
  value: 'test@email.com'
}
//This fails
{
  property: 'email',
  value: 2312
}
//This passes
{
  property: 'newsletter',
  value: true
}
//This passes
{
  name: 'email',
  value: 'test@email.com'
}
```

Hope what I'm trying to accomplish is clear enough, if not I'm happy to elaborate more. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think, the following types will do what you want:

```
// ensure return type of boolean or string
type StringOrBoolReturn = {
  [K: string]: boolean | string
}

export interface HubspotFields extends StringOrBoolReturn {
  newsletter: boolean;
  name: string;
  email: string;
}

// support either property XOR name
type ApiData<K extends keyof HubspotFields = keyof HubspotFields> = {
  property: K
  name?: never
  value: HubspotFields[K]
} | {
  property?: never
  name: K
  value: HubspotFields[K]
}
```

```
function sendApiData<K extends keyof HubspotFields>(data: ApiData<K>) {/*... logic ...*/}

sendApiData({ something: 'email', value: 'test@email.com' }) // ✖
sendApiData({ property: 'something', value: 'test@email.com' }) // ✖
sendApiData({ property: 'email', value: 2312 }) // ✖
sendApiData({ name: 'email', property: "email", value: 'test@email.com' })  // ✖
sendApiData({ property: 'newsletter', value: true }) // ✔
sendApiData({ name: 'email', value: 'test@email.com' })  // ✔
sendApiData({ name: 'email', value: 'test@email.com' })  // ✔
```